# ms access how to reset attachment in form (clear) using button?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to have a **reset button** for my form. My form contain an attachment column. When I used the code below for my form, it's work except for **`Me.Attachment.Value = ""`**.

Thank you for your kind help :)

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()

Form.Refresh
Me.Regulation.Value = ""
Me.Link.Value = ""
Me.Link2.Value = ""
Me.Attachment.Value = ""
Me.Comment.Value = ""
Me.PIC.Value = ""
Me.Date_Stamp.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your form bound to a recordset? If so, you don't need the '.Value' part. And, what error / message / behavior do you get for the line you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NULL` when wanting to reset a field to `nothing`. "" is an actual zero-length string so any field that does not accept a string as a value would fail. I would also get rid of `.value` everywhere.

```
Me.Regulation = NULL
Me.Link = NULL
Me.Link2 = NULL
Me.Attachment = NULL
Me.Comment = NULL
Me.PIC = NULL
Me.Date_Stamp = NULL
```

Comment: *"I would also get rid of .value everywhere."* - Why?

Comment: Not only is it superfluous but on occasion it has worked for me less reliably than just omitting it

Comment: It is not superfluous, it is *specific*. `.Value` is often treated as the default property and omitting it works in many cases but there are also circumstances where it doesn't, i.e., where `Me.Whatever` could be interpreted as a legitimate *object* reference and mean something quite different from the `Me.Whatever.Value` *property*.

Comment: @GordThompson @SunKnight(),  the result is still the same when i'm using my previous codes. It works **except** for `Me.Attachment`. From what I discover, attachment have 3 file attached = `Attachment.FileData` , `AttachmentFileName` and `Attachment.FileType`.